# Can anyone explain this small piece of code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was looking at one of the custom implementations of `ng-blur` (I know it's already available in the standard AngularJS now). The last line is what I don't understand.

```
.controller('formController', function($scope){

$scope.formData = {};

$scope.myFunc = function(){
    alert('mew');
    console.log(arguments.length);
}
})
.directive('mew', function($parse){
      return function(scope, element, attr){
        var fn = $parse(attr['mew']);
        element.bind('blur', function(event){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                fn(scope);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

In the view there's a simple `mew="myFunc()"` applied to inputs.

My question is why are we passing the scope to the function in the very last line of the directive. I tried to make it work without that but it doesn't. What's actually happening?

Also this too works `scope.$apply(attr.mew)`. Same reason or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$parse` only does *just that*, it parses the string passed in, you need to call the resulting function with the current scope because otherwise how else would it know which function to call?

`scope.$apply` works in the following manner:

> 1. The expression is executed using the `$eval()` method.
> 2. Any exceptions from the execution of the expression are forwarded to the `$exceptionHandler` service.
> 3. The watch listeners are fired immediately after the expression was executed using the `$digest()` method.

The reason `scope.$apply(attr.mew)` is due to the fact that it's doing all of the above. It is parsing, and then applying the result of the parse to the scope.

Another option is to use an isolate scope to bind your directive to the `mew` attr.

```
   return {
        scope: {
            mew: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var fn = scope.mew;
            element.bind('blur', function (event) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    fn();
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/S2NWf/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My understanding was that scope.$apply already does the figuring out of which scope to call it in part. Just confused that we have to specify it again.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope that is clearer? Well scope.$apply does, that's why `scope.$apply(attr.mew)` works, so you could take out that extra parse step if you want to go that route.

Comment: He shouldn't remove the scope.$apply!

Comment: @haimlit Could you explain why? I haven't run the code through JSFiddle.net so wasn't sure why it wouldn't work? Is it because the blur event is out of the digest loop?

Comment: @haimlit Thanks for that, I updated my answer with a saner piece of code :)

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example it will work, but as you said, the blur is out of the digest loop. In most of the use cases the function will change data on one scope or another, and the digest loop should run and catch those changes.